# Streaming videos from google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, video-streaming, exoplayer

My MainActivity.java:

```
PlayerView exoPlayerView;
SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
String url="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sAQsndXPmqaEPUKAaCmz9N6cnosJ0StE/preview";
String url="http://blueappsoftware.in/layout_design_android_blog.mp4";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    exoPlayerView=findViewById(R.id.exoPlayerView);
    try{
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter=new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelector trackSelector=new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
        exoPlayer= ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,trackSelector);

        Uri videoUri=Uri.parse(url);

        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory=new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ExoPlayerVideo");
       ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource=new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(videoUri);

        exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}}
```

I have tried using the exoplayer for viewing videos from urls. Although blog urls are working fine for the same code but its not streaming videos from the google drive links although they are made public. As you can see in my code snippet that the url can be viewed easily form any browser as long as you have the url.
Is there any solution for this in exoplayer or I have to use anything else to stream the videos?

The error I am getting for loading the video is:

Source error.

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor, AmrExtractor) could read the stream.
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:931)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:853)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47702209/1841839

Comment: Since I'm streaming an mp4 file, so dashmedia source should not be required. Is there any specific method for viewing google drive videos.